# C#: How should TCP socket buffer data be handled? As bytes or converted to an ascii string?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

C#: How should TCP socket buffer data be handled? As bytes or converted to an ascii string?

I am using methods that are involved in parsing specific data from the returned tcp socket buffer, which practice would be best?

Should I process/parse my data in it's raw byte form? Or should I process it after convert it to an ascii string since string datatypes have niftier text operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, as bytes. It's basically binary data - it's up to the protocol above TCP that to *interpret* that binary data appropriately.

Now, what *is* your data? Are you in control of the protocol? If so, is it *meant* to be text data? Converting binary data for an image (for example) into ASCII is likely to be disastrous... but if it's a genuinely ASCII-only protocol, it's probably the right way to go.

If you don't know the protocol, don't perform any conversions: they may well lose information unless you're very careful (e.g. using base64 instead of just an ASCII encoding).

If you *do* know the protocol, that should dictate how you treat the data.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the buufer data is aways "raw" bytes, so if you want to parse the content you'll have to convert the byte[] into a string. For exemple:

```
string myString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myBufferData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the data being contained in the buffer. If it's a string it's convenient to convert the buffer to a string.

Also note, that you should prepend some header data before you send the string. Like length of the data payload, checksum/parity etc. Network is a non-deterministic environment, and you can't say for sure who sends what on a specified port, you might get a hard-to-trace crashes if you just convert the received buffer directly into a string.